# How do I POST to a web page using Firebug?

Tags: http, post, firebug

How do I POST to a web page using Firebug?

Comment: You want to submit form data using Firebug?

Comment: I actually want to submit some JSON data to a REST service I'm working on...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

AFAIK Firebug can't do this. However, there is a very useful Firefox extension, in the spirit of Firebug, called [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966). This should be able to do what you want.

It allows you to monitor each request made by the browser, and you can turn on an option that allows you to look at, and edit, every single request before it gets sent.

Comment: Sick, thanks for the tip. Had been using Poster, but it sucks

Comment: hm, I didn't see a way to Post through Tamper Data.

Comment: @Bozho, took me a bit to figure out as well. You have to Start Tamper, then request or refresh your page.

Comment: Info from the future: you *can* make an XHR POST since Firefox 3.5: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11604647/245966

Comment: @thesmart Poster's alright for simple stuff, but if there are a lot of moving parts or weird formats I'd tend to agree with you. Modding packets in firebug is a way nicer option...

Answer (score 41):

You can send **POST** request to any page by opening console (e.g. in FireFox **ctrl + shift + k**) and typing simple JS:

```
var formPost = document.createElement('form');
formPost.method = 'POST';
formPost.action = 'https://www.google.com'; //or any location you want
document.body.appendChild(formPost);
formPost.submit();
```

Comment: Nice one. Requires neither jQuery nor a pre-existing form.

Comment: Got to love this answer, as it works with almost any browser. One tip to make this even better is that you need to `createElement('input')`, set its `value` and add it to your `formPost` with `appendChild`.

Answer (score 23):

Firefox 27 (maybe earlier versions too, never checked) has built-in developer tools to modify and resend requests. If you don't have Firebug installed, the console is available by pressing the F12 key. If Firebug is installed, press `Ctrl+Shift+K` instead.

[image]

Comment: Best answer for my case. I was aware of the other extensions like Tamper Data but i really wanted to do this without adding another one here and i already have Firebug. Just don't forget to change content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` if you're doing a standard POST request.

Comment: Best answer for me. No need for extra plugin and very simple way to tweak post/get requests.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old question, but I recently stumbled upon the same problem and wanted to share the method I am using.

Assuming the web site you want to POST to has a form with method="POST" (a very likely scenario), you can use Firebug's JavaScript command line to programmatically submit a POST request. Just click the "Show Command Line" icon in Firebug and enter something like this in the narrow text box at the very bottom of the window:

```
    document.forms[0].submit()
```

Maybe this helps someone.

Comment: BTW, if the page happens to use jQuery, you don't even need a form, you can use the jQuery AJAX API to build a POST request on the fly in the Firebug JS console. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 6):

Another simple solution is to load any webpage that uses jQuery, and type up a $.post() in the console.

Answer (score 4):

[HTTP resource test](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/http-resource-test/) is a firefox plugin that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Another powerful Firefox plugin to perform post request and some more features is the [Hackbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/hackbar/).

Answer (score 1):

Related: 
To resend a POST already made, right click the POST request in the Net/XHR view and click "Resend".

Using Firebug 1.12.0:

Answer (score 0):

Got here looking for a Firebug way of doing this. Then I realized that I could use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/). This is the most powerful tool I know when it comes to debugging web requests.

> Fiddler The free web debugging proxy for any browser, system or
>   platform

Click the [Composer tab](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Generate-Traffic/Tasks/CreateNewRequest) and write your request as desired - then click Execute.

Comment: Fiddler is Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

## NO NEED of plugins !!

Just drag any url in **BOOKMARK BAR**, then right click and **EDIT**, and insert javascript code:

[image]

```
javascript:var my_params=prompt("Enter your parameters","var1=aaaa&var2=bbbbb"); var Target_LINK=prompt("Enter destination", location.href); function post(path, params) {   var form = document.createElement("form");   form.setAttribute("method", "post");   form.setAttribute("action", path);   for(var key in params) {  if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");      hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);      hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);         form.appendChild(hiddenField);  }   }   document.body.appendChild(form);  form.submit(); }   parsed_params={}; my_params.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {var s = item.split("="), k=s[0], v=s[1]; parsed_params[k] = v;}); post(Target_LINK, parsed_params); void(0);
```

then enter the target site-link, and click that button in **BOOKMARK BAR**! **That's all!**

( *source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38643171/2377343* )