# Figuring out url made in ajax post

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping

At this [link](http://www.sbrforum.com/betting-odds/nba-basketball/) when hover over any row, then there is an image box which says "i" you can click to get extra data. Then navigate to Lines History. Where is that information coming from? I can't find the URL that is connected with that.

I used dev tools in chrome, and found out that there's an ajax post being made:

```
Request URL:http://www.sbrforum.com/ajax/?a=[SBR.Odds.Modules]OddsEvent_GetLinesHistory  
Form Data: UserId=0&Sport=basketball&League=NBA&EventId=259672&View=LH&SportsbookId=238&DefaultBookId=238&ConsensusBookId=19&PeriodTypeId=&StartDate=2014-03-24&MatchupLink=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sbrforum.com%2Fnba-basketball%2Fmatchups%2F20140324-602%2F&Key=de2f9e1485ba96a69201680d1f7bace4&theme=default
```

but when I try to visit this url in browser I got `Invalid Ajax Call -- from host:` 
Any idea?

Comment: looks like a POST request, which you can not replicate with the browser search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you say, it's probably an HTTP POST request.

When you navigate to the URL with the browser, the browser issues a GET request, without all the form data.

Try curl, wget, or the javascript console in your browser to do a POST.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: That would be a different, and very much redundant question :-) Here's a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230140/how-do-i-post-to-a-web-page-using-firebug/11886281#11886281